# Create a single color arbitrary size picture data url in javascript?

Tags: javascript, png, gif, data-uri

Does anybody know how I can create an "arbitrarily" sized picture data url, with a single color - without using canvas?

Basically, I'd like to create a GIF or PNG with a certain color and size. I need this to create place holder images with the correct dimensions, while waiting for the server to send proper images.

I want this because it will perform well on a mobile phone, in combination with width: 100%. The image would consume the correct amount of pixels.

I don't want to use canvas because I imagine it would be slower than altering a couple of bytes in a data URL.

Comment: http://www.matthewflickinger.com/lab/whatsinagif/bits_and_bytes.asp

Comment: Have you tested the performance of a canvas? I imagine a single create, rectangular write, and read to URL will be faster than pseudo-binary string manipulation.